# Who developed SHA-2 family?

Tags: sha-2, history

When I look up who developed SHA-2 family, [the result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2) I get is along the lines of

> SHA-2 was first published by the National Institute of Standards and
> Technology (NIST) as a U.S. federal standard.

What I am really looking for is "Which individuals have developed SHA-2 family?". I understand, that most probably there are many induvial behind its development, but like any other scientific endeavor, some individuals have contributed more than others. So I am really trying to know what individuals have directly contributed the most to the development of SHA-2.

I hope the answer provides a broader perspective on how we can identify the individuals who have made significant contributions to a publication developed by a large organization, such as NIST.

Comment: NSA designed SHA-1 and SHA-2 behind closed doors. <https://handwiki.org/wiki/SHA-2>.

Comment: The fact that the above doesn't apply for SHA-3/SHAKE is also [noted](https://keccak.team/keccak_strengths.html) as a strength by Team Keccak.

Comment: but why behind closed doors? I assume they knew it is going to go public and I do not think this is a classified material. Those individuals should be proud of their work, so what was the problem with revealing their identities?

Comment: The *why* can often only be found by asking the organization (in this case I don't think that educated guesses will suffice). Usually that is tricky when it comes to the NSA. Sometimes information may leak out, usually *after* an employment has ended and the person sharing the information feels secure enough to share (e.g. the information on how the SEC / p-curves have been created has been shared, although since they claimed to to have used a random from a HSM the information is still impossible to verify).